# file.choose() analogue for objects in R

Tags: r

Is in R an analogue to file.choose() function,working with objects inside R
(elements of vectors, objects in environments and etc)?
I need just dialog window like in file.choose() function, where i can choose elements of vector, for example

For Example 
 I have dataframe with 3 columns.

```
length(unique(df$column2))
[1] 3
```

Then i write

```
df<- filter(df, column2 %in% MyMagicFunction() )
```

Then i see window, where i choose right elements =)

Comment: If this is for interactive use only, you could try pressing the tab button after the %in% to get a list of columns to choose from, assuming you use rstudio

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are working in pure R console for that (ie. not RStudio)
You can use `file.choose` for that purpose after having populated some fake files, see:

```
myfunction <- function(df){
  split_path <- function(path) {
    rev(setdiff(strsplit(path,"/|\\\\")[[1]], ""))
  } 


  tmpdir <- file.path("c:/temp",substitute(df))
  dir.create(tmpdir,showWarnings =FALSE)
  for (ivar in names(df)){
    cat("", file=file.path(tmpdir,ivar))
  }
  selvar <- choose.files(default = paste(tmpdir,"*",sep="/"), caption = "Variable",
                         multi = FALSE)
  varname <- split_path(selvar)[1]
  unlink(file.path(tmpdir,"*"))

  print(varname) # to be replaced by your function exploiting df and varname such as mean(df[,varname])

}
```

then:

```
>     doit <- myfunction(iris)
[1] "Sepal.Length"
```

as said in comment, you have to define your own function call within `myfunction`.